# Restrict user to enter abuse words in text view

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am developing a application where user has to enter only holy words. I want user to be restricted not to enter the abuse or adult word.
I have a big list of adult or abuse words whenever user will enter that word it should delete it automatically.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "holy words"?  Are you sure that's what you mean?  Anyway it looks like you want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: i dont want anyone to write my code, i just want the idea how can i make it possible if words matches with my listed adult words.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems to be simple to handle shouldChangeCharactersInRange and compare entered words with your dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using `UITextField` so you should look after forbidden words after text has changed:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSRange spaceRange = [newString rangeOfString:@" "];
    if (spaceRange.location != NSNotFound) { // it's a new word
        newString = [self stringWithoutForbiddenWords:newString];
    }
    textField.text = newString;
    return NO; // we set the textField text manually
}

- (NSString *)stringWithoutForbiddenWords:(NSString *)string {
    for (NSString *forbiddenWord in self.forbiddenWords) {
        NSRange forbiddenWordRange = [string rangeOfString:forbiddenWord];
        if (forbiddenWordRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            // remove the forbidden word
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:forbiddenWord withString:@""];        
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

Don't forget to set you `UITextField` delegate.

Comment: I think the OP will need a *white list* as well, that will outbid the *black list*.  For example: "Has anyone been to Scunthorpe?".

Comment: @amit soni Please let me know if it is what you are looking for. If it's not, please provide me some more information.

Comment: @KlimcazakM i am having a list of words and when user will start entering the words after space if that words matches with my blacklisted words then i need to remove that.

Comment: @amit soni I've updated the code, now it should fit your needs.

Comment: @amit soni Is your problem solved? If not, please precise what's missing, if yes, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its a very simple logic , by the way only "Holy Word" seems very funny I hope you meant  non-abusive words.

- So to restrict abusive words, first make an Array and store all the abusive words in that.
- then in `textView shouldChangeTextInRange:` check whenever user press " space.

---

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if([string isEqualToString:@" "])
   {
      //now iterate the whole string and find whether any word contains any value from your Abusive words Array and replace the word with blank space or *

    }
```